# How can I make style changes in the preferences visible in my activity

Tags: android, textview, preferences, background-color

I want to make it possible, that the user of my app can change the style of my app. So he should be able to decide, whether a background picture is shown, the textSize/textColor of different textViews, the background color of the activity.

How is that possible?! I know how to set up a style or a theme, but i don't know how to change the it by the users decision..

Can you help me please?!

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change an Activity style at runtime, but only to existing styles. So you could have, say, 3 styles defines in different XML files, list those 3 to your user, have them select one, and set the style using `Activity.setTheme()`. You would then have to destroy the view and recreate it. Android doesn't currently support any other methods of changing the style at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

What you need in your preferences is a `ListPreference` like:

```
<ListPreference android:key="theme" android:title="@string/theme"
    android:entries="@array/theme_names" android:entryValues="@array/themes" />
```

Then in arrays.xml add something like:

```
<array name="themes">
    <item>dark</item>
    <item>light</item>
    <item>purple</item>
</array>
<array name="theme_names">
    <item>@string/dark</item>
    <item>@string/light</item>
    <item>@string/purple</item>
</array>
```

And then use [setTheme()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29) in `onCreate()`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String userTheme = prefs.getString("theme", "dark");

if (userTheme.equals("dark"))
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Dark);
else if (userTheme.equals("light"))
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Light);
// etc...

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

What this means is that you may need to restart the activity, so that `onCreate()` gets called again. But, alternatively, you could call `setTheme()` in `onResume()` and re-inflate the view hierarchy, so that the theme is effective when returning from the preferences, without requiring a restart of the activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it in the next hours ;)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can give the user the possibility to select its individual textSize?

Comment: Your're welcome. About textSize, this is different question. Here you said "I know how to set up a style or a theme, but i don't know how to change the it by the users decision". IMO you need to ask or look for another question regarding theming and textSize.

Comment: Okay okay.. But I can't solve my Problem. My application doesn't load the theme if i set it in the code. I made it in the way you said, but my application stays in theme Theme.Black (I think that's default, because that field I left empty in the Manifest)..

Comment: I think it works now. I had to call in over super.onCreate :)

Comment: Is there any way to store @style references in the typed array "themes" so that userTheme could be of type int and you could directly set the theme rather than doing string comparisons to figure out which theme to set?

Comment: @olivierg Great answer! Just what I was looking for.  One comment, shouldn't your `equals` parameter be getString(R.string.dark) to ensure consistency.  Otherwise you need to make two updates if a string literal is changed.

Comment: @toobsco42 Did you ever ask your comment as a separate question?  If I will as I would like to implement what you have suggested.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I have not asked my comment as a StackOverflow post.  But I am interested in an answer, because I would like to avoid doing string comparisons if there is an alternative.